# Is it mix blood, mixed blood, or mix blooded?

Tags: word-choice, offensive-language, derivational-morphology

Suppose I wanted to say:

> That's her ____ daughter?

Would I say:

*mix-blood,*

*mixed-blood,*

*mix-blooded,*

or

*mixed-blooded*?

I kind of confuse with adjectives whether it goes with -ed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142126/discussion-on-question-by-mallimika-is-it-mix-blood-mixed-blood-or-mix-blooded).

Answer (score 1):

It should be mixed blood daughter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: To explain, your answer is listing as a low-quality post because, even if correct, it looks like an opinion. Supporting sources would show it's more than your own thought.